# Proving connectedness of a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

What are the best ways to prove that the following set is connected:

$$A_j=\{(x,y):0<y<1/j\}$$

Comment: What is your definition of connected? Do you have any helpful theorems about connectedness?

Comment: A set is disconnected if it is the union of two nonempty subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$, neither of which intersects the closure of other one. A connected set is a set that is not connected.

Answer (score 2):

It is a product of the intervals $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $(0,1/j)$, which are connected.